# access parametrically values of variables inside environments

Tags: r

Let's say we have one or more environments and variables in them.
My question is how we access the values of these variables, parametrically.

```
rm(list = ls())

env1 <- new.env()
env1$var1 <- "value1"

env2 <- new.env()
env2$var2 <- "value2"

env <- ls.str(mode="environment")        # We get the environments

var <- ls.str(eval(parse(text = env[1])))# We get the variables of an environment

eval(var[1])                             # We fail to get the value of a variable

get(var[1], envir=env[1])                # It does not work, either
```

Thank you all, in advance

Comment: You mean something like `get("var2", env2)`?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I should have used get().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `get`, specifying the environment you expect to find the object:

```
get(var[1], envir=env1)
[1] "value1"
```

So, if you want to specify both arugment parametrically, use:

```
get(var[1], envir=get(env[1]))
[1] "value1"
```

Comment: If it is to work parametrically we should use:
get(var[1], envir=env[1]) # but it does not work, either

Comment: @Apostolos OK, I've edited my answer. You need to use `get()` twice.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found with your help:

```
get(var[1], envir=eval(parse(text = env[1])))
```